# AWS Odoo Installation Site Not Displaying

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, odoo

New to AWS and Odoo and Odoo is not coming up after I installed it on a Ubuntu server hosted on AWS EC2.

I may have missed something.

The Ubuntu server is running
and there is an instance running for the public access.

Odoo was started via SSH using Putty.

A domain name has not been directed to the server yet but when I enter http://ServerPublicIP:8069 the connection times out. When I do an IP lookup on the IP only, it resolves to one of the Amazon servers.

So no doubt I have not completed something or have done something wrong. Any ideas as to where to start to resolve this?

Comment: same issue I'm facing now for me.. did you sorted it out ..?

Comment: check your security rules in aws, whether 8069 is added or not

Answer (score 1):

The port 8069 is not open by default for incoming connections for new EC2 instances.

You must add a Custom TCP Rule in the AWS Security group for port 8069 and address 0.0.0.0/0
[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

I came across a really good blog which will help you to install Odoo 11 on AWS EC2 free tire.  Follow the link [here](https://sortedodoo.com/step-by-step-guide-to-install-odoo-11-on-aws-ec2/)

It has provided simple step by step procedures right from creating an Amazon AWS  Account to installing Nginx.

You will be able to install and configure Odoo 11 on AWS EC2 along with Nginx. Apart from this, blog also helps with the Secure Shell connection to server using Putty. Blog also provides steps for Server file management using FTP client program like Filezilla.

In short, it a complete procedure which will help you to install and manage Odoo on AWS EC2 cloud platform. If you find anything difficult and need more help then you can also refer the guided step by step video tutorial reference provided in the blog.

Hope this helps!